# Did every booster of Unglued contain basic land?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[So says wiki](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Booster_pack)

On the other hand unglued basics are listed as "Common" (implying shared sheet with other commons) on [Gatherer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=9677), [official product information](http://www.wizards.com/magic/generic/cardlists/Unglued_Checklist.txt).

Gatherer shows them as silver-bordered, but they appear black-boredred on actual photos.

Anyone has a definite source one way or the other?

(Unhinged/Unstable black bordered lands which were definitely on a separate sheet)

Comment: As another data point, Gatherer is also rendering Unhinged basic lands with a silver border, and they are listed as having the "basic land" rarity.

Comment: I don't have a source, thus comment, but I have opened enough packs back in the day to say yes

Answer (score 1):

Every pack of Unglued *should* contain a basic land, barring any collation issues.

After fourth edition all large sets used a separate sheet for basic lands, but small sets still had their lands printed on the common sheet (why use extra sheets when you have 110-121 slots to fill?).

While the sheet distribution for Unglued isn't known, at 94 cards it definitely falls into the small set category, and most likely only had two print sheets.